# hyperref fully justifies the parts in my TOC?

Tags: hyperref

My MWE below centers my TOC the way I'd like except the `\usepackage{hyperref}` fully justifies the Parts. E.g., "Part One: The First Part" is fully justified:

[image]

When I comment out `\usepackage{hyperref}` the Parts are centered the way I'd like:

[image]

How can I have the Parts not fully justified when using `hyperref`?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\let\ordinal\relax

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% Chapter
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}\hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

% Part
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{}%
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{\centering\huge\scshape Part #1: }
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{}%
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}

\patchcmd\l@part{%
  {\cftpartfont {#1}}\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{%
  #1\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{\typeout{patched}%
}{}

% Spacing
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{50pt}

% Document
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction}
\part{The First Part}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well the code for the link from hyperref readds the grouping that your patch removed.  The best would be if memoir supported hyperref directly, then hyperref wouldn't have to interfere.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. I didn't realize my `patchcmd` was causing the issue. I achieved the same effect with some `\hfil`s and will post an answer.

Comment: the patchcmd doesn't cause the issue, the new group from hyperref is the problem, your patchcmd is now useless.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not using the patchcmd anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments, I didn't realize that my `patchcmd` was the issue. I removed it and achieved the same effect by inserting some `\hfil`s as shown in my updated MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <<===== This causes formatting issue
\let\ordinal\relax

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% Chapter
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}\hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

% Part
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\hfil\hfil} % <=== insert \hfil\hfil
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{}%
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{\hfil\huge\scshape Part #1: } % <=== insert \hfil
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{}%
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}

% Spacing
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{50pt}

% Document
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction}
\part{The First Part}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\end{document}
```